# ExtJS: Container with rectangle in panel not visible

Tags: extjs, panel, draw, invisible, rect

i´d like to replace the html div in following panel by an Ext.Container containing a rectangle.
HTML solution, which is in comment brackets, works fine, but the container alternative is not visible. There is no error shown by firebug. {{var}} are parsed and no problem. var task is later added to another panel with hbox layout. Don´t mind that height etc. is not the same of both solutions. First i just want to make any rectangle visible.

```
var bar = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    items: {
        xtype: 'draw',
        sprites: [{
            type: 'rect',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            fillStyle: 'blue'
        }]
    }
});

var task = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    border: true,
    height: '100%',
    title: '{{name}}',
    titleCollapse: true,
    width: 70,
    listeners: {
        render: function () {
            this.getEl().dom.title = '{{name}}. Start: {{start}}. End: {{end}}';
        }
    },
   items: [bar]
   /* html: '<div class="bar" style="margin-top: {{top}}px; height: {{height}}px"></div>'*/
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing into the container, i used the style attribute of it:

```
   style: {backgroundColor: '#1d5b94'}
```